# Compare two strings in client-server using java

Tags: java

i'm about make client-server app in java but the main probelm is i can't make compare between tow strings

this is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
     DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);//oepn datagram with port
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        String pass = "123";
        int count = 0;
        while(true)
           {
              DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);//get data
              serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);//datagram socket

              String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());//store string
              //String sentence =  receivePacket.getData().toString();
              if(sentence.equals("123"))
              {
                  System.out.println(sentence.equals("123"));
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println(sentence.equals("123"));
              }
              System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);//print it
              InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
              int port = receivePacket.getPort();
              String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
              sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
              DatagramPacket sendPacket =
              new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
              serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
           }
  }
}
```

here in this method it's not working with me `sentence.equals("123")` can you help me to make string compare?

Comment: Are you receiving an Exception? If so, can you please share it? Or how the code is failing?

Comment: Could you see what is the value of sentence ?

Comment: no it's just give me false when i make compare !!

Comment: What is printed for the line `System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);//print it`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to make a guess I suspect that you are comparing something like:  `"123         "` and `"123"` which would be different strings.  When you print them out then they look the same, but in actuality they have different content.  Try printing some lengths `sentence.length()` and see if that differs.  It may contains a \n or some other whitespace character.  You may need to strip that from being sent to the server or pull that off the packet's payload before converting it to a string.  Bear in mind you are converting things in platform specific format when you do `new String( byte[] )`.  You may need to use a character encoding to make sure the two machines sending data are sending them in the same encoding.

```
new String( byte[], String charset )
```

Comment: Hey , you're right the length is different

Pass Length : 3 Sentence : 1024

Comment: That's because you passed it a byte[] buffer of 1024, and it filled that buffer up with the 3 characters in the packet, but that buffer is still 1024 in size.  UDP is a fixed size packet so you may need to encode your data differently to handle variable size payload.  Possibly sending the length in the first byte of the packet, or use a null terminator to signify the end of the data within the packet.  Since we don't see your server side we can only guess how you are encoding packets on the server.